# Using AWS To Process Large Amounts Of Data With Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I have about 300,000 transactions for each user in my DynamoDB database.

I would like to calculate the taxes based on those transactions in a serverless manner, if that is the cheapest way.

My thought process was that I should use AWS Step Functions to grab all of the transactions, store them into Amazon S3, then use AWS Step Functions to iterate over each row in the CSV file. The problem is that once I read a row in the CSV, I would have to store it in memory so that I can use it for later calculations. If this Lambda function runs out of time, then I have no way to save the state, so this route is not plausible.

Another route which would be expensive, is to have two copies of each transaction in DynamoDB and perform the operations on the copy Table, keeping the original data untouched. The problem with this is that the DynamoDB table is eventually consistent and there could be a scenario where I read a dirty item.

Comment: That is what AWS Batch is for.

Comment: @JakubKania That would not solve the memory problem, AWS Batch is more of a orchestrator. Thanks for the tool,I will see if I can tailor something around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serverless is ideal for event-driven processing but for your batch use-case, it is probably easier to use an EC2 instance.

An Amazon EC2 t2.nano instance is under 1c/hour, as is a t2.micro instance with spot pricing, and they are per-second pricing.

Comment: An EC2 may be the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough detail here to make a good suggestion. For example, how is the data organized in your DynamoDB table? How often do you plan on running this job? How quickly do you need the job to complete?

You mentioned price so I'm assuming that is the biggest factor for you.

Lambda tends to be cheapest for event-driven processing. The idea is that with any EC2/ECS event driven system you would need to over provision by some amount to handle spikes in traffic. The over provisioned compute power is idle most of the time but you still pay for it. In the case of lambda, you pay a little more for the compute power but you save money by needing less since you don't need to over provision.

Batch processing systems tend to lend themselves nicely to EC2 since they typically use 100% of the compute power throughout the duration of the job. At the end of the job, you shutdown all of the instances and you don't pay for them anymore. Also, if you use spot pricing, you can really push the price of your compute power down.

Comment: The data scheme has hashkey as userID and sortkey as time_transID. The default dynamo ordering is sufficient for me. It seems like a job for an EC2 instance instead of lambda, the jobs will be ran at spots throughout the day ranging from a couple of seconds to minutes. As you said I think this may be a job for an EC2 instance.